# Continuously check for radio button status [WxPython]

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a listbox with a set of strings. The set of strings I want to display depends on which radio button is selected. I would like it such that while the user is interacting with the Form, if they ever change the radio button it will update the list box.

Here is my code (I'm leaving `the array for t87 and t89` out because they are very long (assume they exist):

```
 def OnBtnSuperTesting(self, event):
    class MainWindow(wx.Frame):

        def __init__(self, parent, title):

            self.dirname=''

            wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(320,440))
            self.SetBackgroundColour(wx.WHITE)
            self.CenterOnScreen()
            self.CreateStatusBar()
            self.radioT89 = wx.RadioButton(self, -1, 'T89 only', pos = (2,0), style = wx.RB_GROUP)
            self.radioT87 = wx.RadioButton(self, -1, 'T87 only', pos = (154, 0))
            self.radioKeySort = wx.RadioButton(self, -1, 'Sort by Key', pos = (2,40), style = wx.RB_GROUP)
            self.radioAtoZ = wx.RadioButton(self, -1, 'Sort Name A-Z', pos = (2,60))
            self.radioZtoA = wx.RadioButton(self, -1, 'Sort Name Z-A', pos = (2,80))
            self.checkCode = wx.CheckBox(self, -1, 'Generate Code', pos = (154,40))
            self.checkBuild = wx.CheckBox(self, -1, 'Generate Build Report', pos = (154, 60))
            self.ln = wx.StaticLine(self, -1, pos = (0,15), size = (300,3), style = wx.LI_HORIZONTAL)
            self.ln2 = wx.StaticLine(self, -1, pos = (150,15), size = (3,100), style = wx.LI_VERTICAL)

            self.radioT87.Bind(wx.EVT_RADIOBUTTON, self.updateList)
            #self.Bind(wx.EVT_RADIOBUTTON, self.radioT89, self.updateList())




            self.listbox = wx.ListBox(self, -1, pos = (0,120), size = (300,200), choices = T89, style = (wx.LB_SINGLE|wx.LB_HSCROLL))
            self.go = wx.Button(self,-1, label = 'Go!', pos = (110, 325))



            # Setting up the menu.
            filemenu= wx.Menu()
            menuAbout= filemenu.Append(wx.ID_ABOUT, "&About"," Information about this program")
            menuExit = filemenu.Append(wx.ID_EXIT,"E&xit"," Terminate the program")

            # Creating the menubar.
            menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
            menuBar.Append(filemenu,"&File") 
            self.SetMenuBar(menuBar) 

            # Events.
            self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnExit, menuExit)
            self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnAbout, menuAbout)

            self.SetAutoLayout(1)

            self.Show()



        def OnExit(self,e):
            self.Close(True)  # Close the frame.

        def updateList(self):
            if  self.radioT87.GetValue() == True:
                choices = T87
                self.listbox.Set(choices)
            else:
                choices = T89
                self.listbox.Set(choices)
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MainWindow(None, "Supervisory Testing")
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: This is a situation where you would `Bind` and event ... ...

Comment: Care to elaborate? Im new to this program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create each radiobutton you can create a bind event. What this does (as you have implemented later on in your code) is execute a command function when the bind event occurs. In your case it would look like this:

```
self.Bind(wx.EVT_RADIOBUTTON,self.RadioButton,self.DoSomething)
```

Explanation:

```
wx.EVT_RADIOBUTTON
```

This is the event that is triggered when the user changes the Radiobutton's status. It may or may not have attributes.

```
self.RadioButton
```

This is the radiobutton which you would like to bind. In your case "self.radioAtoZ" or similar.

```
self.DoSomething
```

THis is the callback function. You can make it whatever you want such as:

```
def DoSomething(self):
    if self.radioAtoZ.getStatus():
        rearrangeNumbersFromAtoZ
        print 'Re-arranged numbers from A to Z'
    else:
        etc.
```

EDIT:

```
self.RadioButton.Bind(EVT_RADIOBUTTON, self.DoSomething)
```

Your structure for self.DoSomething should be like this:

```
Class MainWindow:
     def __init_(self, parent):


     def DoSomething(self):
         #dostuff
```

Also in response to your other comment:
when a function is called within a Bind event, it passes the event to the function by default. In addition, all functions have the "self" arg, thus 2 given args. You need to change the following:

```
def DoSomething(self, event):
      #dostuff
```

Comment: I did research for the answer. Soemtimes you just dont find it.

Comment: It happens, or sometimes you cant understand the answers. If this worked for you please approve it so I can get enough reps to post. Thanks.

Comment: It didn't work unless I did something wrong. I'm getting the error:    AttributeError: 'MainWindow' object has no attribute 'updateList'

I added "self.Bind(wx.EVT_RADIOBUTTON, self.radioT87, self.updateList())"
and "def updateList(self):"

Comment: The above error was simply because i didnt have the def idented right. However, I now get:

 in Bind
    id  = source.GetId()
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'GetId'

Comment: Try: self.RadioButton.Bind(wx.EVT_RADIOBUTTON, self.DoSomething)

Comment: AttributeError: 'MainWindow' object has no attribute 'updateList'

Comment: post your code by editing your original question. I need more than just the error to figure out exactly what you're doing wrong. See my edit as well.

Comment: It almost works with your edit, i put teh function in the right spot and now i get this: TypeError: updateList() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Comment: You need to create the update list function and place it under your MainWindow class. Right now your indentation is wrong. You need to backspace the UpdateList so that it is under MainWindow and not under __init__

Comment: I was able to fix it all. For some reason the def DoSomething needs (self, e) not just (self). Then I had to move T87 and T89 into that definition because they were not global variables. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I decided to rewrite the OP's code to demonstrate how to bind 2 RadioButton's to 2 different event handlers and update the ListBox:

```
import wx

########################################################################
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Radios!")
        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.radioAtoZ = wx.RadioButton(panel, label='Sort Name A-Z',
                                        style = wx.RB_GROUP)
        self.radioAtoZ.Bind(wx.EVT_RADIOBUTTON, self.sortAZ)
        sizer.Add(self.radioAtoZ, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)

        self.radioZtoA = wx.RadioButton(panel, label='Sort Name Z-A')
        self.radioZtoA.Bind(wx.EVT_RADIOBUTTON, self.sortZA)
        sizer.Add(self.radioZtoA, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)

        choices = ["aardvark", "zebra", "bat", "giraffe"]
        self.listbox = wx.ListBox(panel, choices=choices)
        sizer.Add(self.listbox, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

        self.Show()

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def sortAZ(self, event):
        """"""
        choices = self.listbox.GetStrings()
        choices.sort()
        self.listbox.SetItems(choices)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def sortZA(self, event):
        """"""
        choices = self.listbox.GetStrings()
        choices.sort()
        choices.reverse()
        self.listbox.SetItems(choices)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

You will want to take a look at the following wiki article on the differences of binding it this way versus the other:

- http://wiki.wxpython.org/self.Bind%20vs.%20self.button.Bind

Most of the time when you create a group of widgets that do different things, you bind them to different event handlers. If you want to bind all the RadioButtons to the same handler, then you'll probably need to name each widget with a unique name so that when they come to the handler, you can tell which button was pressed. Then you can use a series of **if** statements to decide what to do to the list box. Here's a tutorial that talks about that sort of thing:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2011/09/20/wxpython-binding-multiple-widgets-to-the-same-handler/

Comment: This is nice, but you've removed all the formatting I had so i cant really use this very much. If you look at the editing you'll see I have essentially what youre doing but I have some error: "TypeError: updateList() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)"
if you could help identify the problem there taht would be great.

Comment: updateList is an event handler. When an event fires, it will pass "self" and an event object to updateList. Thus updateList needs to accept 2 arguments, not one.